# Python NoneType error when attempting to access object functions

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to add a player to a board in python, but am struggling with the implmentation.

The player object's attributes gets validated when a player is initiated via the `operator` library. I want to show the exceptions as they occur; ie. put the initiation of each player in a try-except.

Problem is that when I do it as I am bellow I get an error saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./main.py", line 88, in
>   move
>       r.forward() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'forward'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./main.py", line 161, in
>   
>       main()   File "./main.py", line 141, in main
>       move(choice, player)         # Peform the moves on the player   File "./main.py", line 91, in move
>       Try again!\n>>> ".format(err, r.initial[0], r.initial[1], r.initial[2])) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'initial'

The operations mentioned above are movements handled by the player class (`player.py`). It's clear that I am somehow returning a NoneType, but I'm not sure why this is occuring.

It happens when I have entered an incorrect player-position during initiation and then add a correct one.

So basically this is what I do:

1. Initiate the board
2. Initiate a player outside of bounds (or on another player)
3. Initiate a correct player position.
4. Error occurs.

However, there are no errors if I add players correctly (ie. step 3 doesn't occur).

```
def add_player(board):

    try:
        choice = input("Please enter the current player's initial position.\nRemember to keep inside board's limits!\n>>> ").split()
        if len(choice) == 3 and validate_player(choice[0], choice[1], choice[2]): # Check the length of supplied input and check type-integrity

            return Player(int(choice[0]), int(choice[1]), choice[2], board)       # Initiate a player with the supplied input. Each player is assigned to a Board (many-to-one relation).

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        add_player(board)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that calls `forward`, we aren't going to be able to diagnose the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may give you ideas on how to validate user input without using recursion, which may make your stack traces more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible problems here. Firstly, if the `if` statement does not evaluate to True, nothing is returned from the function. No exception would be raised so the except block wouldn't be entered, but nothing else is returned either; None is the default return value when nothing else is returned.

Secondly, even if there was an exception, you are not returning the result from the recursive call to `add_player` in the except block. However you should not be using recursion here, you should loop until the right values are entered.

Unrelated, but you should never catch the base Exception; you should only catch the things that you might expect, which in this case are ValueError (from the `int` call, if something other than a number is entered) and IndexError (from the indexing into list, if less than three items are entered). Catch those exceptions only.